# Scala Seq[Seq[SomeClass]] type mismatch for mutable collection

Tags: scala, collections

I encountered an issue that is related to multiple Seq nesting and mutable collections. If I use a Seq[Seq[SomeClass]] and use mutable collection for the Seq, it will produce a type mismatch in IntelliJ as `Type mismatch, expected: String, actual: SomeClass`. If I ran it, it will throw

> value += is not a member of Seq[SomeClass]. Expression does not convert to assignment because receiver is not assignable.

The code is as following. The error is at `k1Class.students += mary`, which is commented in the code.

```
package core

import scala.collection.mutable
import scala.collection.mutable.{ArrayBuffer, ListBuffer}

case class Student(age: Int, name: String)
case class Class(topic: String, students: Seq[Student])

object Test2 {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val grades = mutable.HashMap[String, Seq[Class]]()
    val classes = ListBuffer[Class]()
    val students = ArrayBuffer[Student]()

    val bob = Student(7, "Black")

    students += bob

    val musicClass = Class("music", students)

    classes += musicClass

    grades += ("k1" -> classes)

    val k1Classes = grades.get("k1").get

    for (k1Class <- k1Classes){
      val mary = Student(7, "Brown")
      //!!! Error here!!! Type mismatch, expected: String, actual: Student
      k1Class.students += mary  
    }
  }
 }
```

I am quite lost why this is happening. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to compile with two small changes.

```
import scala.collection.mutable.{ArrayBuffer, ListBuffer, Seq}
                                                          ^^^
```

and

```
  k1Class.students.update(0, mary)
```

Such heavy reliance on mutability is generally discouraged, but we all have to start somewhere.

Comment: Also better to `import scala.mutable` and then use `mutable.Seq` so it is clear in the code that you are using the mutable version not the default immutable one.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. Any reasons why I cannot use k1Class.students += mary here? Also, what would be a better way to handle the situation where the collection is changing constantly without using to much mutability?

Comment: As you can see from the [Scaladocs page](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/Seq.html), there simply is no `+=` method on a `mutable.Seq`. Why not? Hard to say. Maybe the authors of the Standard Library just missed it. As for going immutable, you have to start thinking of a `List` with a new element as a different list, not the old list with new content. It takes some getting used to but it's an important aspect of Functional Programming.

Answer (score 0):

> If I use a Seq[Seq[SomeClass]] and use mutable collection for the Seq

What matters here is the static types. The type of `k1Class.students` is `Seq[Student]`, and this is the `Seq` imported by default: `scala.Predef.Seq` which is an alias for `scala.collection.Seq`. So it isn't mutable and doesn't have `+=` defined.

Comment: That makes senses. But what puzzles me is that why it works for: 
   ' val grades = mutable.HashMap[String, Seq[Class]]()
    val classes = ListBuffer[Class]()
    val musicClass = Class("music", students)
    classes += musicClass
    grades += ("k1" -> classes)' classes here is defined as scala.collection.Seq, and then latter been implemented as a ListBuffer, which should be a mutable.Seq. But the compiler didn't complain here. Why is this?

Comment: "classes here is defined as scala.collection.Seq". No it isn't. It's inferred to be `ListBuffer[Class]` from the initializer. To define it as you say you need to write `val classes: Seq[Class] = ListBuffer[Class]()` and you'll see the compilation fails again.